# Hbase storage engine

Tags: storage, hbase

What storage engine is used in hbase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think JohnJohnGa was asking about the storage engine and not the file system.
I believe this link is more informative: http://www.larsgeorge.com/2009/10/hbase-architecture-101-storage.html.
Also good reading material is here: http://www.slideshare.net/raveenvr/datastores.
The authors compare the storing engine of several solutions including MongoDB and HBase.

Hope this helps

Frank

Answer (score 0):

Quoting wikipedia, it seems [**HBase**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/HBase) :

> runs on top of [**HDFS** (Hadoop
>   Distributed Filesystem)](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Hadoop_Distributed_Filesystem#Hadoop_Distributed_File_System)

See also [HBase's FAQ](http://hbase.apache.org/book/faq.html#faq.hdfs.hbase).